# Insert marker from leaflet map to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sqlite, flask

I am trying to insert a point into my sqlite database. I have created a marker on my map, that opens a popup where I can type in an adress and send it via post request to the database, however the statement does not create a new row with the given x,y and adress data. Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/marker', methods=['POST'])
def draw():
    conn = g.db.cursor()
    x = request.form['x']
    y = request.form['y']
    desc = request.args['desc']
    conn.execute('''INSERT INTO my_table(id, adress, geom) VALUES (1111111, '%s', GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 3857))''' % (desc, x, y))
    result = conn.fetchall()
    return result
```

Comment: no, they are not exactly as shown. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement does not return anything.

To read data from the database, you must use a SELECT query.

Comment: Yes I know, but the INSERT statement creates a new row , which is missing in the database my_table

Comment: if I try `select*from my_table` the table is empty